# Subclassing an UIButton: custom behaviour on "touchUpInside"

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, subclass

I am subclassing an UIButton which is going to be present in all of my app's ViewControllers, kinda Navigation Button. I would like just to put it to my VC and apply custom class, without any code in ViewController itself. So, the questions:
1. is it possible?
2. I am using this code now in my UIButton custom class. What is wrong?:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self addTarget:self action:@selector(didTouchButton) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)didTouchButton {
    NSLog(@"YEAH, it works, baby!");
}
```

UPD: seems that even `initWithFrame` method is not being called at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading from the nib I think.The initWithFrame method doesn't work if not called programatically.

Try `-awakeFromNib` Method

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16146107/1704346)